# Why are my RSpec specs running twice?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have the following RSpec (1.3.0) task defined in my `Rakefile`:

```
require 'spec/rake/spectask'
Spec::Rake::SpecTask.new(:spec) do |spec|
  spec.libs << 'lib' << 'spec'
  spec.spec_files = FileList['spec/**/*_spec.rb']
end
```

I have the following in `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spec'
require 'spec/autorun'
require 'rack/test'
require 'webmock/rspec'

include Rack::Test::Methods
include WebMock

require 'omniauth/core'
```

I have a single spec declared in `spec/foo/foo_spec.rb`:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe Foo do
  describe '#bar' do
    it 'be bar-like' do
      Foo.new.bar.should == 'bar'
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `rake spec`, the single example runs twice. I can check it by making the example fail, giving me two red "F"s.

One thing I thought was that adding `spec` to the `SpecTask`'s `libs` was causing them to be double-defined, but removing that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem using **zeus**, and removing `require 'rails/autorun'` from my `spec_helper.rb` stopped it for me

Comment: I do not have this line and I am still having this problem. Any other idea?

Comment: The best advice i can give you right now is to upgrade to rails 4.1, and get Spring built in, which will allow you to stop using Zeus altogether.

Answer (score 10):

Duplication configurations in spec_helper.rb and .rspec was causing my tests to run twice.

e.g.

**.rspec**

```
--color
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.color = true
end
```

So it appears to duplicate the test when you have the SAME configure setting duplicated in .rspec and spec_helper.rb

Comment: Having the `.rspec` file alone made it run twice, I didn't even need the duplicate settings

Comment: I had `--color` and `--format d` in my `~/.rspec` and `config.color = true` and  `config.formatter = :documentation` in my code. Had to get rid of the duplicates to not have rspec running twice (didn't matter if I removed from code or config file).

Comment: More info: "You're adding two formatters, so getting double the output", says rspec owner at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1929#issuecomment-90771361

Answer (score 8):

Turns out Rails has default `spec` task, so if you are using Rails, the solution to the problem would be to clear pre-defined task and then re-initialize your custom logic, like this:

```
# ... beginning of Rails Rakefile
Rails.application.load_tasks

Rake::Task["spec"].clear

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  # your logic here
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not directly related to the question as this apparently concerns Rspec versions from 2 onwards, but as the title of the question is the same that brought me here, I mention to others who might find this page for the same reason, that having `rspec.rake` in your `lib/tasks` can cause the `rake spec` to run all spec tests twice. Removing that file helped me (as was suggested at: http://www.patrickgannon.net/post/519eed022c17433fc8000018/rake-runs-rspec-tests-twice)

Answer (score 3):

I observed a similar thing.  But in my case it's not that the tests ran twice, they were printed twice.

The reason for this, I found out, is that I alias `rspec` to `rspec -f d -c` (formatting documentation and color).

And the spec_helper.rb contains

```
config.color = true
config.formatter = :documentation
```

So essentially this information is duplicated.  After I run `unalias rspec`, I run my tests again, the problem is fixed.

You may also have a .rspec file that contains similar info:

```
--format d
--color
```

This could also result in the duplication.  So modify or move this file.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this fixes the problem, but you can use `require 'spec_helper'` instead of `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'`

Also, `'spec/autorun'` will `require 'spec'` for you.

The only other thing I can think of is that you have two spec tasks defined in your system. Is this a rails app? If so, make sure you're not duplicating a rake task that already exists in `lib/rake/tasks`.

HTH,
David

Comment: It's not a Rails app, so that's not the problem. I can only do `require 'spec_helper'` if my `$LOAD_PATH` is already set up, but if I want to run a single spec, `$LOAD_PATH` won't get set until inside `spec_helper.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

We had this issue today at my company and it was for another reason not noted in here: We were auto-loading some files which contained test logic. These were then being run when the code was required in the first place:

```rb
# Require support, concerns, lib, validators dirs
%w(support concerns lib).each do |dir|
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/#{dir}/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
end
```

The solution is to remove auto-loading code. This kind of code in Rails + tests is not very conventional, and usually points to poor file structure.

Comment: I'm using factory_bot_rails. I has added a linting test under `spec/factories/factory_bot_spec.rb`. It was running twice. Once I moved it to `spec/models/factory_bot_spec.rb` it started running only once.

Answer (score 1):

Other cause, also in the spec_helper.rb is using the following code:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    #config stuff
end
```

The tests were executed only once after removing this code.

Comment: [I had configuration code where you have the comment](http://i.imgur.com/sApPy0a.png). Removing it made my tests run once. I'm not sure why. Looks like I'll need to use `~/.rspec` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There was a `.rspec` file in my home directory, while I also had my projects `.rspec` in the current directory.

Removing the extra `.rspec` file from the home directory fixed it for me.