# Guard runs my specs twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm pretty sure Guard is the culprit, as running `rspec` runs all specs once. Running `guard` and `enter` results in all specs being run twice. Not sure why. Googled to destruction, and common gotchas, such as requiring 'rspec/autorun' in the spec_helper.rb are simply not the cause of it.

It can get quite annoying when the specs are starting to get slow!

.rspec

```
--color
--order default
```

Guardfile

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard :rspec do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.slim)$})          { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml|slim)$})     { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    Capybara.run_server = false
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
    Capybara.default_selector = :css
    Capybara.server_port = 7171
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :feature

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

*Update*

This may give a clue

```
$ guard
06:40:31 - INFO - Guard is using GNTP to send notifications.
06:40:31 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
06:40:31 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
06:40:31 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
06:40:31 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/starkers/Desktop/boxshare'
[1] guard(main)> 
06:40:35 - INFO - Run all
06:40:35 - INFO - Running all specs
```

Notice the two info logs at 06:40:31 that Rspec is running...

Comment: What versions of Guard and RSpec are you using?

Comment: I run Guard/Spork server in a separate terminal window. I notice that my 'guard' terminal window runs new tests first, then my 'main' window shows the same output. But if I re-run the same test, the 'guard' window doesn't re-display. Do you use a separate window for your guard server?

Comment: @Chiperific I do indeed.

Comment: @DanielBerkompas The latest versions. And yes, this is still an issue 6 months on!

Comment: I've also seen this behaviour intermittently in some apps and not others. Odd.

Comment: @sevenseacat Tell me about it. Happens in OSX and Ubuntu...

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting all_after_pass: false? The default should be false, but its worth a shot.

Comment: Can you tell me please if specs are run with gap between runs or in one sequence? If there is gap (showing overall performance) then it is normal behavior.

Comment: @Vladson There's no gap but they appear to be separate: `17:03:05 - INFO - Running all specs` ... `17:03:28 - INFO - Running all specs` Is that what you mean?

Comment: I believe this once happened to me after udpdating some gems. Did you try experimenting with different versions of rspec-rails?

Comment: @Starkers, yes. Seems that guard receives signal to run twice. Or, when Guard had ran all the specs in the recently changed part of app successfully - it will run all the test suite. It may be related to the IDE used, as guard is trekking file modified time.

Comment: I run into the same issue (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030308/why-are-my-rspec-specs-running-twice) - and the tip that solved for me was migrate from zeus to built in spring: http://girders.org/blog/2014/02/06/setup-rails-41-spring-rspec-and-guard/

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I had this problem too. Guard was running all of my rspec tests twice. It turns out that I had run `guard init rspec` twice and my `Guardfile` had the `guard` ... `do` ... `end` stanza duplicated.... doh.

Comment: Thanks! I've had the same problem. I 've just deleted Guardfile and run guard init rspec to get rid of all duplication.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this issue several times. The problem is often (but not always) caused by a duplicated RSpec setting. Try removing the `config.order = "random"` line from spec_helper.rb, since you already have that setting in your .rspec file.

Comment: Could have been it, but sadly didn't work for me personally. I've updated the question with what could possibly be a clue :)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with option `all_after_pass`.

Just changed my guard command on `Guardfile` to `guard :rspec, cmd: 'rspec', all_after_pass: false do` and it stopped.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guard-dev/t1xxZpI5oWA
https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec#list-of-available-options